# Hyperledger Fabric chaincode throwing error while installation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to install chaincode written in golang. When I execute the installation command - `peer chaincode install -n chaincode -v $CC_VERSION -p chaincode`, it returns the following error after few seconds:

```
Error: error getting chaincode code chaincode: error getting chaincode package bytes: Error obtaining imports: command <go list -f {{ join .Imports "\n"}} chaincode>: failed with error: "timed out after 1m0s"
```

Last few lines of logs:

```
2021-01-03 04:49:24.666 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 035 Signing identity expires at 2029-11-11 17:12:00 +0000 UTC
2021-01-03 04:49:24.666 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2021-01-03 04:49:24.756 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 037 parsed scheme: ""
2021-01-03 04:49:24.756 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-01-03 04:49:24.756 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 039 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0-org1:7051 0  <nil>}]
2021-01-03 04:49:24.756 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03a ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-01-03 04:49:24.756 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0001f6b00, CONNECTING
2021-01-03 04:49:24.774 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0001f6b00, READY
2021-01-03 04:49:24.825 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03d parsed scheme: ""
2021-01-03 04:49:24.825 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03e scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-01-03 04:49:24.825 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03f ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer0-org1:7051 0  <nil>}]
2021-01-03 04:49:24.825 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 040 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-01-03 04:49:24.825 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 041 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000272e90, CONNECTING
2021-01-03 04:49:24.828 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 042 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000272e90, READY
2021-01-03 04:49:24.889 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 043 Obtaining default signing identity
2021-01-03 04:49:24.889 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 044 Using default escc
2021-01-03 04:49:24.889 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 045 Using default vscc
2021-01-03 04:49:25.312 UTC [chaincode.platform.golang] getCodeFromFS -> DEBU 046 getCodeFromFS chaincode
Error: error getting chaincode code chaincode: error getting chaincode package bytes: Error obtaining imports: command <go list -f {{ join .Imports "\n"}} chaincode>: failed with error: "timed out after 1m0s"
```

I also tried to compile and build the chaincode by executing `go build` command and it successfully generated the binary without throwing any error.

Comment: Could you tell me the version of the fabric network?

Comment: @myeongkilkim 1.4.1

Comment: Can you tell me whether the peer command is executed on the host pc or the fabric-tools container (CLI)? If it is a host pc, can you give the absolute path of the current chaincode path and the $GOPATH value? If running with CLI, can you provide additional GOPATH volume mounting information in docker-compose? In addition, it will be clearer if you provide information on imported libraries of chaincode.

Comment: @myeongkilkim I am using fabric-tools. The chaincode is in `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/src/chaincode` and the GOPATH is `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer`

Comment: There are some doubts. Attaching the docker-compose.yaml file of fabric-tools to the question seems to be able to answer more accurately. First, let's assume that you have volume mounted by matching your GOPATH and fabric-tools GOPATH in docker-compose.yaml. In that case, it is necessary to check whether the version of `$GOPATH/src/github.lcom/hyperledger/fabric` matches well with 1.4 (probably 1.4 is presumed to be the peer directory). The pass seems to be wrong. First, enter the path under `$GOPATH/src` for the -p option.

Comment: That is, if your chaincode path is `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/src/chaincode`, you have to enter `-p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/src/chaincode`. do.

Comment: @myeongkilkim I fixed the error. Actually my GOPATH was wrong. Not sure how I made this stupid mistake

Comment: haha, I thought so, so I asked for confirmation. got it, good luck!